# Draggable slider HTML and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface

I'm looking for a draggable slider that works on touch devices. I cannot use an input range element because it needs to be styled for ie9, can anyone recommend a good tutorial or an open source component somewhere?

jquery ui is sadly not an option here either. I need the bare bones and I'll handle everything else myself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

html5 have dragable objects..but in html 4 you must use js, with css

or  using dom you can do this but not efficient.
see this 
    [Drag & drop in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470119/drag-drop-in-html)